# how to prevent popup javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have link

```
<a onclick="return package_tour_order(14400287396);" href="javascript:;">advanced</a>
<a>doit</a>
```

need to get value from onclick only ID nubmer, but this

```
return package_tour_order(14400287396) is javascript function that popup new window with informationabout that ID
```

if i run this code

```
$('a:contains("advanced")').attr('onclick').match(/\d+(?=\))/)[0]
```

**it works fine** but when i run in my project with that javascript function(this function is loaded from another site) its does not work and popup window

i need to disable onclick somehow and get only that ID number, how can i doo that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make it a link. Make it a span or whatever. Also... what do you mean by "function is loaded from another site". If the script is loaded that should not influence things.